# Using LazyLoad.js with Wordpress Loop

Tags: jquery, filter

I'm trying to use LazyLoad.js to fadein my images on scroll. (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

It seems to be working well for images that I manually code in, because I'm able to manually change "src" to "data-original".

The problem I'm having is integrating this with the loop "" function.

I came across this, but I'm not sure how to implement it:

```
add_filter( 'img.lazy', function( $src ) {
    return "' data-original='$src";
});
```

I'd like to change all of my "" tags to "" tags dynamically, while also adding a class of "lazy" to each.

Is this do-able?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WordPress` [lazy load plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load/) instead of integrating a `JavaScript` lazy load plugin manually in to you `WordPress` installation, if you use this, you don't need to write a single line of code and it's really very good, (I'm using it for years).

> **Lazy Load**
>
> Lazy load images to improve page load times. Uses jQuery.sonar to only
>   load an image when it's visible in the viewport. This plugin is an
>   amalgamation of code written by the WordPress.com VIP team at
>   Automattic, the TechCrunch 2011 Redesign team, and Jake Goldman (10up
>   LLC). Uses jQuery.sonar by Dave Artz (AOL).

Just install it from admin panel and activate the plugin and you are done. Also, check [this collection](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wp-image-performance-plugins/) for image optimization.

**Installation :**

You can easily install it from your admin panel, go to `Plugins->Add New` and put `lazy load` in the `keyword` input box then press `Search Plugins`, it'll show you a list of some plugins, just click the `Install Now` link of appropriate plugin and it'll be installed and then click `activate plugin` link from the page you are on and that's it.

**Screenshot :**
[image]

Comment: I guess the question is "how to use lazyload.js with wordpress", a custom code, coded for a specific need, not a plugin that loads in every page ( even when i its not needed ).

Comment: I think, the answer was a solution and it's accepted :-)